# QT QRegularExpression QRegularExpressionMatchIterator not working (SIGSEGV)

Tags: regex, qt

I'm trying to use QRegularExpression and it's been working fine for all my patterns exept this.

I have this text:

```
TYPE "ASDF"
   some content
END_TYPE

TYPE "QWER"
   some other content
END_TYPE

TYPE "ZXCV"
   blablablabla
END_TYPE
```

and I want to match all TYPE...END_TYPE blocks (3 matches) in a QRegularExpression like this

```
QRegularExpression re("(TYPE(?:[^E]|E[^N]|EN[^D]|END[^_]|END_[^T])*END_TYPE)", QRegularExpression::DotMatchesEverythingOption);
QRegularExpressionMatchIterator i = re.globalMatch(text);
while (i.hasNext()) {
    QRegularExpressionMatch match = i.next();
    if (match.hasMatch()) {
        QString captured = match.captured(0);
        //.. and do some stuff with that string
    }
}
```

but when I build and debug the code I get a Segmentation fault error window at the QRegularExpressionMatchIterator:

> The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the Operating System. Signal Name: SIGSEGV, Signal meaning: Segmentation fault

I've also tried using negative look-arounds:

```
(TYPE ((?!END_TYPE))+END_TYPE)
```

This does not give me an error but also gives me no match.

Does any one have any idea what I'm doing wrong here or suggestion on how I can improve the regular expression? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated :)

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to do with that regex pattern.  If you just want to capture the TYPE...END_TYPE blocks, why don't you just use something like `(TYPE [\s\S]+?END_TYPE)`

Comment: When you debug, does it show `re` as defined? Does `i` ever get defined? From what you've described, it seems like `re` is null.

Comment: @RyanJ, This has something to do with QRegularExpression not supporting the (?:[^E]|E[^N]|EN[^D]|END[^_]|END_[^T]). If I use this pattern re("(TYPE.*END_TYPE)), then I don't get that error but I will just get one big match instead of three.

Comment: @CAustin, (TYPE [\s\S]+?END_TYPE) does not give me a match. what does that "[\s\S]+?" do? The reason that the regex is bit hard to read is because I have to make sure that it doesn't just capture the first TYPE and last END_TYPE at the bottom (one match instead of 3)

Thank you for taking the time to help me out :)

Comment: You can use `re.setMinimal(true)` to enable non-greedy matching. Then you can use `(TYPE [\s\S]+?END_TYPE)` to match each group sequentially.

Comment: `[\s\S]` is simply a character set that includes all whitespace characters and all non-whitespace characters.  It's an easy way to match everything without having to use a switch that tells the dot to match newlines.  Anyway, it sounds like what you're doing is trying to implement your own way of making the pattern non-greedy, which is simply what the `?` does after `+` or `*`.  Ryan J's suggestion might help.

Comment: @RyanJ, I tried your suggestion and got this build error: 'class QRegularExpression' has no member named 'setMinimal'. Looks like this method does not exist. how ever it does have the QRegularExpression::InvertedGreedinessOption (wich is supposed to be the same). I set the  re.setPatternOptions(QRegularExpression::DotMatchesEverythingOption | QRegularExpression::InvertedGreedinessOption); but still there is no match for that pattern "TYPE [\s\S]+?END_TYPE)"

Comment: It works if I skip the [\s\S] and just do a .+ with non-greedy pattern. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Ok with great help from **RyanJ** and **CAustin** I solved my problem. this is how the code looks now:

```
QRegularExpression re("(TYPE .+END_TYPE)");
re.setPatternOptions(QRegularExpression::DotMatchesEverythingOption | QRegularExpression::InvertedGreedinessOption);
QRegularExpressionMatchIterator i = re.globalMatch(text);
while (i.hasNext()) {
    QRegularExpressionMatch match = i.next();
    if (match.hasMatch()) {
        QString captured = match.captured(0);
    }
}
```

It looks like QRegularExpression does not support negative look-arounds like (TYPE ((?!END_TYPE))+END_TYPE) or grouping like (TYPE(?:[^E]|E[^N]|EN[^D]|END[^*]|END*[^T])*END_TYPE)

So the fix is to use the **QRegularExpression::InvertedGreedinessOption** (works the same as QRegExp::setMinimal()) for minimal matching.

Thank you RyanJ and CAustin for your help!

Comment: Qt is a picky beast... glad you got what you needed.