# QRegularExpression match on a multiline string is not working

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I m working on an editor highlighter and i faced a problem with multiline patterns.

The code that i want to highlight looks like this.

```
1   var f_content string
2   var f_path string
3   lcs f_content <
4   this a multiline string
5   hello
6   how are you 
7   fine?
8   >
9   lcs f_content "test string"
10  lcs f_path "file_path.txt"
11  file write f_path f_content
```

All the keywords are colored perfectely (i m using around 15 different patterns...i based on the qt code highligher example) except of one which is the text between '<' and '>' (from line 3 to 8)
I tried so different tools such as the famous https://regexr.com/ (most of patterns work here like /<[\s\S]*>/ /<.*>/s ...), I also found a similar person had the same problem as mine [QT QRegularExpression QRegularExpressionMatchIterator not working (SIGSEGV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673671/qt-qregularexpression-qregularexpressionmatchiterator-not-working-sigsegv), i tried his solution but its not working.

My code looks like this:

```
void Highlighter::highlightBlock(const QString &text)
{
    foreach (const HighlightingRule &rule, highlightingRules) {
        QRegularExpressionMatchIterator matchIterator = rule.pattern.globalMatch(text);
        while (matchIterator.hasNext()) {
            QRegularExpressionMatch match = matchIterator.next();
            setFormat(match.capturedStart(), match.capturedLength(), rule.format);
        }
    }
    setCurrentBlockState(0);
}
```

The class constructor (where the patterns are created):
The < > matching is in the block number [4]
already i m using the same logic in the same block for string brtween qutoes "test string" and it is working

```
...

//! [15] // labels
    events.setFontWeight(QFont::Bold);
    events.setFontUnderline(true);
    events.setForeground(QColor::fromRgb(66, 65, 205,255));
    events.setFontUnderline(true);
    //events.setBackground(Qt::darkGreen);

    QStringList eventsPatterns;
    eventsPatterns << "\\bkeyword1\\b"
                   << "\\bkeyword2\\b"
                   << "\\bkeyword3\\b"
                   << "\\bkeyword4\\b"
                      ;


    foreach (const QString &pattern, eventsPatterns) {
        rule.pattern = QRegularExpression(pattern);
        rule.format = events;
        highlightingRules.append(rule);
    }
//! [15]

//! [6] // labels
    label.setFontWeight(QFont::Bold);
    label.setFontUnderline(true);
    label.setForeground(Qt::darkYellow);
    rule.pattern = QRegularExpression("[A-Za-z0-9_.]+(?):");
    rule.format = label;
    highlightingRules.append(rule);
//! [6]

//! [7] // dark line comment
    longComment.setForeground(Qt::darkMagenta);
    longComment.setBackground(Qt::darkMagenta);
    rule.pattern = QRegularExpression("##.*");
    rule.format = longComment;
    highlightingRules.append(rule);
//! [7]

//! [4] // text between quotation marks
    //quotationFormat.setBackground(Qt::gray);
    quotationFormat.setForeground(Qt::darkGreen);
    rule.pattern = QRegularExpression("\".*\"");
    rule.format = quotationFormat;
    highlightingRules.append(rule);
    rule.pattern = QRegularExpression("<.*>", QRegularExpression::DotMatchesEverythingOption | QRegularExpression::InvertedGreedinessOption);
    highlightingRules.append(rule);

//! [4]
```

I am not getting any errors or exceptions. The code works good. Also the same thing for the other 14 patterns.

I hope that somebody helps me because i spent very long long time (weeks) trying to solve this without any result

Comment: Have you tried enabling multi-line matching: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#PatternOption-enum

Comment: Hello @AlanBirtles and thank you for your comment, actually "yes", i tried it. did't change anything